# Does liblinphone in Android support SUBSCRIBE with dialog event?

Tags: sip, linphone

I found a [link](http://www.3cx.com/blog/voip-howto/busy-lamp-field/) describe how BLF(busy lamp filed) works. It is based on Subscribe, Notify commands.

My question is: does Liblinphone in android support this BLF(Busy Lamp Field) function? For example, As user A: sip:a@company.com, I would like to subscribe user b: sip:b@company.com with BLF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method in LinphoneCore can send [subscribe command](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/org/linphone/core/LinphoneCore.html#subscribe(org.linphone.core.LinphoneAddress,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.linphone.core.LinphoneContent)):

```
subscribe(LinphoneAddress resource, java.lang.String event, int expires, LinphoneContent content)
```

Sends an outgoing subscription for a resource with given event, expiration period, and content.

We can specify *event*, it's **dialog** in this case.

Here is the code snippet:

```
String account = "sip:YOUR_ACCOUNT@SERVER_DOMAIN:PORT";
LinphoneAddress address = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createLinphoneAddress(account);
LinphoneEvent dialog = core.createSubscribe(address, "dialog", 300);
dialog.addCustomHeader("Accept", "application/dialog-info+xml");
dialog.sendSubscribe(null);
```

Note: the accept header is optional, but in some server you need this header to avoid **489 bad event** error